# Error on datatable re-initialization

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to destroy data table and re-initialize it with a new set of columns.

**Error :**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null on below line

```
var orig = settings.nTableWrapper.parentNode;
```

Below is how I destroy and initialize table.

```
if($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableHelper.element)){
    dataTableHelper.element.DataTable().destroy();
}

table = dataTableHelper.element.DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                bDestroy: true,
                paging: true,
                ordering: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                scrollX: false,
                fixedColumns: false,
                fixedHeader: true,
                order: order,
                orderMulti: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                searching: false,
                displayStart: 0,
                pageLength: 100,
                ajax: {
                    "url": url,
                    "type": 'POST',
                    "contentType": "application/json",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {

                        return json.data;
                    },
                    data: function (data) {
                        setTableParams(data);
                    }
                },
                columnDefs: dataTableHelper.columnDefs,
            });
```

How should I rectify this error ?

Comment: Instead of destroying and reinitializing, have a look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: I have to destroy and reinitialize because different columns gonna be shown based on user selections on the screen.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting this exact error on this exact line when the table is being destroyed.  I'm using a knockout data-binding here, but oddly, it is only in this one component that leads to this null reference, while other places do not result in a null parent. Can anyone explain why settings.nTableWrapper would be set to null?  calling isDataTable() on the element returns true prior to the error, so the datatable has been initialized..

Comment: @ChrisKnoll did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is the method I use to destroy a DataTable:

```
if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#someTable' ) ) {
    $("#someTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#someTable').empty(); 
}
```